# Execute another block if no records found in block 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, where-clause

I have one SQL Query execution block with below condition.

In first query we appends where condition like below.

```
Declare  @maxprice int 
Declare  @minprice int
```

Query 1

```
Select * FROM Mobiles where value between @maxprice and @minprice and column2= @otherparam
```

if no records found in above query then i want to execute query to with some modification in query 2.

Query 2

```
Select * FROM Mobiles where value between @maxprice - 1000 and @minprice - 1000 and column2= @otherparam
```

as per above condition if no mobile found for specific date range then i want to decrees max and min amount by  1000 RS.

for i.e @maxprice = 10000 & @minprice  = 8000 
if no records found as per above then i want to modify parameter and execute query again,

```
SET @maxprice = 9000
SET @minprice = 7000
```

Currently i am execution Query 1 and if 0 records found then i am execution Query2

Please suggest me how to achieve this with minimum execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE for the 1st query and UNION ALL for the 2nd:

```
with cte as (
  Select * FROM Mobiles 
  where value between @maxprice and @minprice and column2= @otherparam 
)
Select * from cte
union all
Select * FROM Mobiles 
where value between @maxprice - 1000 and @minprice - 1000 and column2= @otherparam 
      and not exists (select 1 from cte)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row:

```
select top (1) m.* 
from Mobile
where value between @minprice - 1000 and @maxprice and
      column2 = @otherparam 
order by value desc
```

For performance, you want an index on `mobile(column2, value)`.

Note:  The order of operands for `between` is quite important.  The smaller value should be the second operand and the larger the last one.

Comment: shouldn't be better to have a `@minprice - 1000` stored in a variable?

Comment: @lakta . . . Ask the OP.   This is answering the question s/he is asking.

Comment: I'm asking as a general performance vice question. As far as i know, it's better to have a calculation in a variable, than to recalculate it for each row

Comment: @lakta . . . The value should be evaluated during the compilation phase.  Even so, adding two numbers would probably be undetectable in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a temp table. Load result of Query 1 in temp. If temp has no data, load result of Query 2 in temp. Show data from the temp

```
Declare  @maxprice int 
Declare  @minprice int 
create table #tmpMobiles (/*... your structue of data*/)

insert into #tmpMobiles
Select * FROM Mobiles where value between @maxprice and @minprice and column2= @otherparam 

if not exists(select top 1 * from #tmpMobiles) begin
    set @maxprice = @maxprice - 1000
    set @minprice = @minprice - 1000

    insert into #tmpMobiles
    Select * FROM Mobiles where value between @maxprice and @minprice and column2= @otherparam 
end

select * from #tmpMobiles
```